# Can't open apt-url links from playdeb in Chromium on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

Chromium asks me if I want to open an external application, I click yes and it just opens a new window. I followed all steps on the playdeb-website on how to install games via the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install the playdeb package first:

1) Download it: `cd ~/Downloads && wget -c http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb`

2) Make it executable: `chmod +x ~/Downloads/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb`

3) Install: `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb`

All in one: `cd ~/Downloads && wget -c http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb && chmod +x ./getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i ./getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb`

Comment: I installed the playdeb package after downloading it from the site. I just double-clicked it. Installing a game didn't work. I then added the repository and the gpg-key. Still doesn't work...

Comment: what is the output of `which software-center` ?

Comment: Nothing :D I installed supertuxcart and assaultcube via synaptic. But I can't install a game via apturl.

Comment: I think that is the problem. Install it: `sudo apt-get install software-center software-center-aptdaemon-plugins`

Comment: You mean the Lubuntu software center doesn't work with apturl?

Comment: I suppose it does not.

Comment: Alright. I think I'll use synaptic then. Thank you mate!

Comment: # Wellcome ;-) #